# Is there a native way to get an array of property values from multiple objects?

Tags: php, oop

I often encounter a situation where I have to get an array of values that come from multiple objects. Let me clarify that with an fictional situation and some code.

Imagine I have created a class...

```
class MyObject {
    public $x = 0;
    public $y = 0;
}
```

I have an array of instances...

```
$instances = array(
    new Object,
    new Object,
    new Object
);
```

and I want to join all `x` properties as strings, devided with comma's... I would have to use a loop...

```
$array = array();

foreach($instances as $instance) array_push($array, $instance->x);

$str = implode(',', $array); // holds an array of all x values
```

That would totally work, but I am very much against unnecessary loops and pro native implementations because I have a little obsession for performance - I dislike looping through huge arrays only to get a single property off every instance.

**Is there a native way to get an array of property values from multiple objects?** If so, how? If not, any idea why not?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple easy way is to use `array_map`

```
class MyObject {
    public $x = 0;
    public $y = 0;
}

$instances = array(
        new MyObject,
        new MyObject,
        new MyObject
);


$str = implode(",",array_map(function($v){ return $v->x;},$instances));
echo $str ;
```

Or `array_reduce`

```
$str = trim(array_reduce($instances, function($a,$b){ $a .= $b->x . "," ; return $a;}),",");
echo $str ;
```

The both would output

```
0,0,0
```

You can also modify your class to use `__toString()` Example

```
class MyObject {
    public $x = 0;
    public $y = 0;
    function __toString() {
        return $this->x . "," . $this->y;
    }
}

$instances = array(new MyObject(),new MyObject(),new MyObject());
echo implode("\n", $instances);
```

Output

```
0,0
0,0
0,0
```

Comment: Ingenious! PHP keeps amazing me with functions I didn't know they existed that are perfectly fit for the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I've found to this problem is to use `array_map()`, like this:

```
implode(',', array_map(
  function ($object) { return $object->property; }, 
  $instances));
```

Comment: OP wants to avoid loop. `array_map` will internally iterate over array. BTW, I can't see any way to avoid iteration in given situation.

Comment: @PLB almost everything is loop .. even time is a loop internally .. the fact you are dealing with multiple instances you can not avoid loop